# Fill/Cover Gap Under White Vinyl Privacy Fence

Tags: fence

I had a white vinyl privacy fence installed. Due to changes in the ground, there are a few places with up to a 5 inch gap between the bottom of the fence and the ground. Is there a way to remove that gap, in order to keep small pets inside? There is a similar, even larger gap under the gates that would also need a similar fix.

Comment: What's your priority, optics or containment?

Comment: Mine is containment, but significant other is likely optics :)

Comment: Then, tbh, you should have discussed it with the builders before they started. They could possibly have made it touch the ground right through whilst keeping the tops all the same height - it would have cost a lot more, as they'd have had to cut it a plank at a time, depending on the fence construction. After the fact now you're left with making a patchwork quilt or filling the gap with chicken wire.

Comment: Can't go back into the past :) So looking for actual advice. Thank you.

Comment: Some pictures would help people understand your problem and offer better solutions.

Comment: You should probably ask about this over on the Pets section of Stack Exchange. It's amazing how small a hole pets manage to wiggle through. If that's your concern, a better approach may be to set up a "catio" or other contained space within the yard rather than trying to secure the yard itself.

Comment: Steve, I was planning to add pictures, but got lazy, my fault, you are 100% correct.

Comment: Thanks, Keshlam, I may do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have been much easier before you put the fence in, but better late than never...

Cut sod (assuming grass on the ground) add up to 5 inches of dirt as needed, replace the sod. Lazy method that may not work if your small animals dig - dump bark mulch along the fence.

Under the gates the approach depends on what the gates are on - if grass or dirt, same fix, if driveway you'll need to build a speed-bump wide enough not to damage your cars and high enough to close the gap.

Comment: to prevent digging use rubble (coconut sized rocks etc) under the dirt.

Comment: Thanks Ecnerwal and Jasen. The sod/dirt idea sounds promising, I may try that when it warms back up.